# How can I add a color gradient to the toolbar (Android)

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, toolbar

I want to add a color gradient to my toolbar (app bar/title bar).

I've created an xml gradient file to the drawable folder called "side_nav_bar.xml".

**side_nav_bar.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
    android:angle="135"
    android:endColor="#7524f6"
    android:startColor="#2691f6"
    android:type="linear" />
```

I found some suggestions on the internet to create a new custom toolbar then set this as the background image etc. But I don't have enough info about this.

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
actionbar.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.side_bar_nav));
```

Comment: Should I add this under onCreate?

Comment: I get 2 errors after inserting this code under onClick.

Comment: 1: "Error:(51, 50) error: incompatible types: android.support.v7.app.ActionBar cannot be converted to android.app.ActionBar"

Comment: 2: "Error:(52, 18) error: cannot find symbol method setBackground(int)"

Comment: You can use android.support.v7.app.ActionBar instead of ActionBar

Comment: OK, I've fixed. Error 1 is gone. What about error 2 (52, 18)?

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work. Now, 2 errors. Here are them:

Comment: 1: "Error:(53, 93) error: cannot find symbol variable side_bar_nav"

Comment: 2: "Error:(53, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable actionBar"

Comment: Now: "Error:(52, 51) error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to Drawable"

Comment: Still: "Error:(52, 41) error: cannot find symbol method getResource()"

Comment: try getResources()

Comment: one last question, it worked only for the toolbar, is it also possible to see it on the status bar? Will making the status bar transparent can be a solution?

Comment: didn't got ur question add in question with ss